# How come I can't update my state?

Tags: reactjs

```
class ProductCarousel extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      active: -1,
      fullScreen: false
    }
    this.flky = {}
  }

  componentDidMount (props) {
    this.flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)
    this.flky.on('select', () => {
      this.setState({ active: this.flky.selectedIndex })
    })
  }

  fullScreen () {
    this.setState({ fullScreen: true })
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render () {
    const images = this.props.images
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='carousel'>
          {images.map((url, i) => (
            <img
              className='productPhoto'
              key={i.toString()}
              onClick={this.fullScreen.bind(this)}
              src={stripUrl(url)}
              style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have this component in js, in the function fullScreen, I expect `this.state.fullScree`n to be true, but it's still false, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is asynchronous. Its second parameter is a callback that you can use to react to when the state was actually updated.

Comment: ok, will a state update trigger a re-rendering of a page(I don't really need to do anything else within this function, I just need the state in another part of the page)

Comment: Yes, setstate will cause a re-render when it has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

setState does not update the state immediately. It create a pending transition instead.

If you want to check the component's state just after setState, do it like this:

```
this.setState({fullScreen: true}, () => {
    // I am triggered after the state is set
    console.log(this.state)
})
```

Read about it over [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)